# Umlauts in filenames are truncated (are shown as question marks)

Tags: utf-8, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

On one of our ColdFusion 10 enterprise / CentOS 6.5 servers umlauts in filenames are saved as `?`.

For example:

```
<CFPROCESSINGDIRECTIVE pageencoding="UTF-8">
<CFSET VARIABLES.umlauts = "ümläüté" />
<CFSET VARIABLES.filename = createUUID() & "-" & VARIABLES.umlauts & ".txt" />
<CFFILE action="write" output="#VARIABLES.umlauts#" file="#expandpath("./" & VARIABLES.filename)#" />
<CFOUTPUT>#VARIABLES.filename#</CFOUTPUT> <!--- outputs something like: A9C9BC8C-983A-5EA6-A4ED411BA0E63C72-ümläüté.txt --->
```

writes a file called `A8B49720-020A-2500-605F4CC73129D07C-?ml??t?.txt` to disk. The content of the file is like expected "ümläüté".
Manual creating files with umlauts in filename is no problem (e.g. `touch äöüß.txt` works like expected).

More details of server:
Java Version: 1.6.0_29
Tomcat Version: 7.0.23.0
Java File Encoding: UTF8

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/i18n
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"

$ locale
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Any ideas what could cause this behaviour?

Comment: Is the name of the file *really* hard-coded in the source code like that, or is that just an example? If it is in the file, you'll need a `<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding=UTF-8">` towards the top of the file.

Comment: That's just example code. The `<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="UTF-8">` does not solve the problem. Umlauts are still `?`.

Comment: No, the processingdirective is only relevant if it IS in the code. Which I did say. If you output the values on the screen, are they well-formed?

Comment: Feels like this question was just asked recently. I will see if I can find the thread.

Comment: yes, output in browser is correct.

Comment: @Leigh, I found it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056883/cfdirectory-with-coldfusion-11-issue-with-non-ascii-characters-in-filenames  ... no solution as of yet. I think the processingdirective answer is a red hering. I still think this is a DISPLAY issue - the underlying file on the disk has to be ok right? It's just the encoding - the way it's output to the page?

Comment: Well I see he DID specify that it outputs the file _incorrectly_ to the disk.

Comment: (Edit) @MarkAKruger - Yep, that is the one. Though on second read it may not be exactly the same issue ..

Comment: I found this user of Open Blue Dragon (an alternative CFML engine) having exactly the same issue and https://code.google.com/p/openbluedragon/issues/detail?id=516 his solution, quoting, was: `It seems like this has been resolved by setting "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8". It seems to be a tomcat problem that it sets question marks for special characters if the charset is unknown.`, or perhaps `"de_DE.UTF-8"`in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll put it out as an answer for more clear visibility.

A user of Open Blue Dragon (an alternative CFML Engine) was having exactly the same issue.

> If I try to upload a file with, for example, the filename "testätest.pdf", then I have the following situation:
>
> - The file, OpenBD stores to my filesystem, is named: test?test.pdf
> - The filename, reported via #cffile.ServerFile# is: testätest.pdf

He later came back with this answer

> It seems like this has been resolved by setting "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8". It seems to be a tomcat problem that it sets question marks for special characters if the charset is unknown.

Or, in the OP's case, to set `LC_All` to `"de_DE.UTF-8"` perhaps.

**Source:** [Issue 516: Special characters (like german "Umlauts") in filenames of uploaded files are replaced with "?"](https://code.google.com/p/openbluedragon/issues/detail?id=516)

Comment: That is the same solution as in [the thread mentioned above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276362/umlauts-in-filenames-are-truncated-are-shown-as-question-marks#comment43023111_27276362). But the lingering question was [*how* to add that setting to CF's custom Tomcat implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056883/cfdirectory-with-coldfusion-11-issue-with-non-ascii-characters-in-filenames#comment42642317_27056883). (I do not know). Any ideas for the other guy?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't either.