# Why are certain characters not being injected correctly to SQL Server from a CFQUERY?

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, cfml, lucee

I have a Coldfusion app running on Lucee which connects to a SQL Server database.

When I run the following query directly in SQL Server Manager:

```
UPDATE article
SET content='20m²'
WHERE id=3159
```

The column gets populated fine with 20m².

HOWEVER, when run from a cfml page which simply runs this:

UPDATE article
    SET content='20m²'
    WHERE id=3159

The column gets populated with: 20mÂ²

As in, this additional Â character appears. This also occurs with some other special characters, but most are fine. Is this to do with some configuration of the jdbc connector? I don't see what the difference should be between the above two? Putting the value in a cfqueryparam tag makes no difference.

Thanks

Comment: What version of CF? You might wanna take a look at `cfprocessingdirective` if less than CF11.

Comment: What sort of column is it? Is it NVarchar? If processing directive doesn't work you can try the unicode syntax `content=N'20m²'` ... Also make sure you use "cfqueryparam" to bind your variable.

Comment: Is your file encoded in Windows1252 or Utf8? Does the server expect the file to have another encoding?

Comment: Seems like an encoding issue of some sort.

Comment: All comments absolutely relevant and helped me understand, although with my above example the cfprocessingdirective tag with the char encoding set to utf-8 worked! Thanks

Comment: @paddyc - BTW, cfprocessingdirective is only needed because the special characters are hard coded *into the cfm file*. If the real code passes the input as some sort of form parameter, it should not be necessary.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler - You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's hard coded, I believe you'll want to make sure you save that file in Unicode UTF-8.

[image]

Also make sure your JVM arguments will process that as well.
Admin > Server Settings > Java and JVM.
Add " -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" to the Arguments.

[image]

Comment: Since there is a db query involved, there is a little more to it than just the change the page encoding ;-) Most likely the hard coding is just for testing anyway. So other side of the question is how to ensure the correct values are transmitted to the database *and* stored properly. It would be good to elaborate on the full cycle ...

Comment: Process of elimination - make sure the file with '20m²' is saving and being read back properly. It could be the db end of things are working fine.